# Ubuntu takes long to attach an external HDMI display

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

When plugging in an external HDMI display to a running Ubuntu 20.04 laptop - it takes ~ 1 minute to attach it. During attaching process it shows a black screen on both monitors.

In previous version (18.x) it was taking few seconds.

The external display is configured and needs to be a primary display. Resolutions of built in and external monitors slightly differs (16:9 and 16:10)

What could cause that?
Where to look for potential problems?

I can not upgrade to 22.04 at the moment.

Comment: Is it x11 or wayland you use?

Comment: @Chokoladekiks x11